# Enforcing minimum DLL version referenced by a registry value

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, wix3

Our app requires a recent version of a DLL in order to function correctly.  The path to the DLL is stored in the registry.  How do I enforce a minimum file version as a launch condition in Windows Installer?

So far I have this:

```
<Property Id="FileTest">
    <RegistrySearch Id="FileSearch"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Company\Product"
                    Name="DLLPath"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Type="file">
        <FileSearch MinVersion="1.2.3.4" />
    </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
<Condition Message="!(loc.ErrorMessage)">Installed OR (FileTest)</Condition>
```

But WiX won't compile this:

```
MainApp.wxs(543) : error CNDL0010 : The FileSearch/@Name attribute was not found; it is required.
```

The problem is I don't know what to enter for the Name attribute.  I don't know in advance what the DLL is named, it could be anything!  (That's why the registry value is there!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you modify the [`RegistrySearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) to this:

```
<Property Id="FileTest">
    <RegistrySearch Id="FileSearchResult"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Company\Product"
                    Name="DLLPath"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Type="file">
        <FileSearch LongName="[FileSearchResult]" 
                    MinVersion="1.2.3.4" />
    </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

I think having FileSearch as both the ID and an actual wix element is causing you and issue. If you change the id to something like `FileSearchResult` and then reference it in the `Name` (or safer, `LongName`) attribute of the [`FileSearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) element (by enclosing it in square brackets, `[]`), then it *should* work. I haven't touched wix in about 6 months, so I make no promises ;)

**NOTE: The square brackets are the way the Wix UtilExtensions (as seen in [this example](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_define_searches.htm)) identify a [`RegistrySearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_registrysearch.htm) result stored in the `variable` attribute. It may not be so for accessing the `Id` holding the result in standard wix.**

**NOTE 2: You may actually need to use a [`RegistrySearchRef`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearchref.htm) element as the parent to the [`FileSearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_filesearch.htm) element instead. Take a look at [this example](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/directorysearchref.htm) (though it uses one result of a [`DirectorySearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_directorysearch.htm) element in another [`DirectorySearch`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_directorysearch.htm)). Hopefully this may give you enough to go on.**

Comment: Actually it turns out that "Name" can be anything - it's ignored completely when FileSearch is a part of a RegistrySearch!  Type some gibberish into "Name" and the search still works.  I don't know why the field is still required in this case.  The technique of using brackets doesn't work by the way, since the corresponding column in the Signature table is just a Text data type, not Formatted.

Comment: Another key thing to do is include the "Language" attribute on the "FileSearch" element, which I was missing.  This was causing searches to fail if the version number I was searching for exactly matched the discovered version number.  (This is all described in the Signature table documentation.)

Comment: Also, LongName is deprecated; it triggers warnings when it's used.

Comment: @JamesJohnston: Great information thanks! I'm sure this will come in handy for my team as well.